# undesirable cropping of Label that has been rotated 90 degrees

Tags: wpf

I am creating 2 columns. left column will show caption of the DataGrid which will be in right column.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Name="FilterLabel">
    <Label.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Label.RenderTransform>
</Label>
```

the problem here is that the lable gets rendered horizontally first, and cropped at 20 pixels. So after it has been rotated, only first few letters appear rendered in left column.

as soon as i make the left column wider, more letters get rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform` so that even the layout calculations are transformed.